# SOUP UI Groovy || For loop is looping 50 times where the condition is using this number anywhere

Tags: groovy, soapui

Here I am just taking value(integer) from Properties file and using the same in for loop.
Note : If I use direct number instead of "getTestCasePropertyValue" value it work as expected. Not getting how loop is looping it 50 times.

Groovy script:

```
def getTestCasePropertyValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "NumOfPayments" )

log.info(getTestCasePropertyValue )

for(i=0; i<=getTestCasePropertyValue; i++)
{

        log.info("Test Print"+i)


}
```

Output:

```
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:2 
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print0 
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print1 
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print2 
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print3 
...
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print50
```

Comment: It would really help, if you could add what is logged here.  Even better: use `getTestCasePropertyValue.inspect()` to output the value (most likely it's a string or some other data type you are no expecting)

Comment: Below is my output where the value of "NumOfPayments" from Properties is 2

Comment: Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:2
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print0
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print1
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print2
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print3
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print4
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print5
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print10

..............................
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print48
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print49
Fri Mar 06 12:58:47 IST 2020:INFO:Test Print50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value from the properties is a String.  You will detect problems like this easier, if you use `.inspect()` to log things.

Also the character `'2'` is `50` as integer, which then the for loop conditions casts this too.

```
def getTestCasePropertyValue = "2"

println(getTestCasePropertyValue.inspect())
// → '2'
println(getTestCasePropertyValue as char as int)
// → 50
```

So best explicitly cast to a number using e.g. `.toLong()` on the string:

```
println(getTestCasePropertyValue.toLong().inspect())
// → 2
```

Comment: Hello @cfrick Thank you for your quick response. I got pointer the resolve my issue and my problem got resolved now by just typecasting from String to int

Comment: def getTestCasePropertyValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "NumOfPayments" )
def NumOfPayments = getTestCasePropertyValue.toInteger()